# How define the COLSPAN of a new Element TD

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have a small problem with IE

With Firefox, I can create a new TD element with a Colspan = TR size :

```
 new Element('td',{'colspan' : '0'})
```

But this code does not work on IE.

Do anybody have a solution ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I choosed an other solution :

```
new Element('td',{'colspan': myTr.childElements().size()})
```

with myTr the previous

Answer (score 0):

There's a [test failure report](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405785%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that acknowledges IE does not support that feature.

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398734/colspan-all-columns/398778#398778), you might want to set `colspan` to a value greater than the total number of columns in your table:

```
new Element('td', {'colspan': '1000'})
```