# How to separate two tr's in an html table

Tags: html, html-table

Is there a possibility to have a visual separator between two lines (`tr`) in an HTML table.

I tried with a `<br>` but this is not valid code.

I tried do add a padding-top to the `tr` after the break but it does not work.

Currently I use an empty line:

```
<tr><td colspan=\"X\">&nbsp;</td></tr>
```

but I don't think this is the best solution, especially as I have to make sure the `colspan` is adjusted if there is a change is the number of columns.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: I actually prefer an 'empty' line. So border is not what a want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edited** to reflect my re-reading the question rather than the *title* of the question (original answer remains below the rule).

If you want a visual separator (rather than simply white-space) then simply use:

```
td {
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; /* or whatever specific values you prefer */
}
```

---

The only way to increase spacing between table rows, that I'm currently aware of, is to use `padding` on individual rows/cells:

```
td {
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vzvUb/)

Although there is the potential to use transparent (or `background-color`-ed borders):

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
}

td {
    border-top: 0.5em solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0.5em solid transparent;
}

td:hover {
    border-color: #ccc;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vzvUb/1/)

Answer (score 1):

The `<tr />` element is not stylable in all browsers however you could always add the padding or a bottom-border to the cells within the tr.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I use separate `tr`s for this purpose all the time. I style them (e.g. the one td within) via a separator class.

About the colspan-problem see [Colspan all columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398734/colspan-all-columns).