# how to check with javascript how many columns given html table has?

Tags: javascript, html-table

That is how is the maximum colspan, for example:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td> 1 </td>
  <td> 2 </td>
  <td> 3 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td> 1 </td>
  <td> 2 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td> 1 </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

should give 3

Comment: plain JS or using a particular framework (jQuery/mootools/etc) ?

Comment: Shouldn't each table row have the same number of columns? Or at least a colspan on the cell(s) of the row with the fewest columns?

Comment: I prefer plain JS. Sorry for not specyfying.

Comment: @Jan That's what I was thinking. If this is the asker's website, he should probably fix things such that all rows have the [same number of columns](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html). If it's not, of course, this is the right way to go about it.

Comment: I also found that `colspan='100%'` sets the `<td>` tag do maximum available colspan. -> here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398734/colspan-all-columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each table has a `rows` array, and each row has a `cells` array. Then it's just a matter a finding the maximum.

```
function calculateCells(){
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    var max = 0;
    for(var i=0;i<table.rows.length;i++) {
        if(max < table.rows[i].cells.length)
            max = table.rows[i].cells.length;
    }
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Find each `<tr>` with "getElementsByTagName()"
2. For each `<tr>`, find each `<td>` similarly
3. Count the `<td>` elements, then iterate through and add "colspan - 1" for each `<td>` with a "colspan" attribute
4. Maintain a maximum count over all rows.

Comment: @Guffa yea, I hate those :-)  You're right though; that would make it ... weird.

Answer (score 2):

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brymck/xpSv3/1/) for an example. As you requested, it's in plain JavaScript:

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var max = 0;

for (var i = 0, iLen = table.rows.length; i < iLen; i++) {
  var temp = 0;
  var cells = table.rows[i].cells;

  for (var j = 0, jLen = cells.length; j < jLen; j++) {
    // This is very important. If you just take length you'll get the
    // the wrong answer when colspan exists
    temp += cells[j].colSpan;
  }

  if (temp > max) {
    max = temp;
  }
}

alert(max);
```

Answer (score 1):

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/YCRP5/) for a jQuery version. It counts the number of `td` elements in each `tr` and checks each time to see if a greater number has been encountered. The `max` variable stores the current maximum number of columns found:

```
var max = 0;
$("tr").each(function() {
   var count = $(this).find("td").length;
    if(count > max) max = count;
});
alert(max);
```