# Table footer auto spanning across width of table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table which has **dynamic number of columns** depending on data I receive.
I have a   tag which needs to spread across all columns independent of number of columns in a table.

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th><span>ColA</span></th>
<th><span>ColB</span></th>
<th rowspan='2'><span>Col<br/>  C</span></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr>
<td>Footer content here</td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

EDIT
colspan = 0 worked for me!

```
<td colspan='0'>Footer content here</td>
```

Works on FF, Did not work for Chrome, IE8 though :(

EDIT 2

colspan = '100%'
This link solved crossbrowser problem
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5028091/405117

Comment: You need to know the number of columns or create a separate table underneath.

Comment: Thanks njk....I was just wondering if there is a way that the footer (which is only one column wide in my case) can spread across the width of table...maybe using css?

Comment: You can certainly move away from using a table altogether to a CSS approach. However, if you're displaying data, table is still the way to go.

Comment: Technically (I know this seems weird!) but the tfoot tag should come just after the thead tag, and the tbody tag should come last

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `colspan="0"`
By the way, your `<tfoot>` should be between `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags.

EDIT: That practice, being recommended by W3C, is not cross-browser. Use carefully!

Comment: This is not supported in all browsers. In fact, last I checked (which granted was a decent while ago), only firefox supported this.

Comment: W3C says: colspan = number [CN]
    This attribute specifies the number of columns spanned by the current cell. The default value of this attribute is one ("1"). The value zero ("0") means that the cell spans all columns from the current column to the last column of the column group (COLGROUP) in which the cell is defined.

Comment: I have never seen this before. Can you provide some documentation?

Comment: About tfoot, W3C says: As a child of a table element, after any caption, colgroup, and thead elements and before any tbody and tr elements, but only if there are no other tfoot elements that are children of the table element.

Comment: @simbirsk Yeah, its been in the W3C specs since day one. Still up to browsers whether or not to support it, though. I would guess all newer browsers support it, but I'd be careful with older versions

Comment: Links for the quotations: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html and http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/tfoot

Comment: I'll edit, because you are right, that's not a 100% cross-browser solution. Thanks!

Comment: @njk from [www.w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-tables-960123) : `COLSPAN, e.g. <TD COLSPAN=2>
A positive integer value that defines how may columns this cell spans. The default COLSPAN is 1. COLSPAN=0 has a special significance and implies that the cell spans all columns from the current column up to the last column of the table.`

Comment: All, here's the SO topic on [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398734/colspan-all-columns).

Comment: @simbirsk thanks! colspan = '0' worked for me. I have updated my question with solution.

Comment: +1 for "`<tfoot>` should be between `<thead>` and `<tbody>`". I was having a weird issue with bottom borders not rendering the full width of the table in Chrome. Moving `<tfoot>` to the conform to spec fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Put a ridiculously high number in the colspan value (i.e. `colspan="9999"`) and add the style `table-layout: auto` to your table element.

Answer (score 2):

Use `colspan`. You'll need to get the number of columns via jQuery, and then set the colspan of the table row you want to stretch, like this:

```
function ColumnCount(){
    var numCols = $("#YourTableID").find('tr')[0].cells.length;
    $('tfoot tr').attr('colspan', numCols.toString());
}
```

And then you'll need to give the id `YourTableID` to the table, like this:

```
<table id="YourTableID">
```

in place of `<table>`.