# Make an HTML table's column span all the columns

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML table and the CSS property `table-layout` is set to `fixed`.

I want one of the cells in the table, the only cell in a particular row, to span all the columns in the table, i.e to fill the entire width of the table.

When I use:

```
<td colspan = "0" id = "tdPager">
```

It works with FireFox v24 and IE 9 and above but does not work with Internet Explorer 8 or below and any version of Chrome.

How do I make the column span the entire table width in all browsers?

I have tried all -- setting the colspan to the values "*", "100%" and even a number higher than the total number of columns but it produces a horrid effect on all browsers. All the columns in the rest of the rows get really thin. I cannot set the colspan to a fixed number equal to the total number of columns because the number of columns is dynamic.

Comment: Could you set colspan to the number of columns in the table?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Colspan all columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398734/colspan-all-columns)

Comment: Failing that, could you set the colspan value to 32767 or some other implausibly high number?

Comment: Note that [`colspan="0"` isn't currently allowed by the HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/tabular-data.html#attr-tdth-colspan).

Comment: I have tried all -- setting the colspan to the values "*", "100%" and even a number higher than the total number of columns but it produces a horrid effect on all browsers. All the columns in the rest of the rows get really thin.

I canot set the colspan to a fixed number equal to the total number of columns because the number of columns is dynamic.

Comment: "I canot set the colspan to a fixed number equal to the total number of columns because the number of columns is dynamic." - You *can*, although I can imagine it might be a lot of work.

Comment: *You can, although I can imagine it might be a lot of work.* @PaulD.Waite: Thank you. That did the trick. :-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are using it incorrectly by setting it to `0`.

You need to set the `colspan` equal to the maximum number of columns that you have in any row of your table.

So, if your table has 6 columns in row 5 and that is the most, then you would set `colspan="6"`.

If the number of columns is dynamic, then you need to set the `colspan` dynamically.

Answer (score -1):

you must specify how many columns you want to span eg: **clospan ="3"**

Answer (score -1):

you can just set the maximum possible no for that many column wont be available in the table

like if you have max 5 column, just set colspan="6" or even more.

Answer (score -2):

`colspan="100%"` seems to work well in IE 10, Firefox 26 and Chrome 31.

Comment: That's accidental, because it's the same as `colspan="100"`. Don't use this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398734/colspan-all-columns explains this further, not always compatible with all browsers...