# Putting a heading on a table

Tags: html, css

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/mVX93/13/

I'm trying to put a heading at the top of my table which stretches all the way across. I thought  was the way to do it.

```
<table id="my-table">
    <tr>
        <th>Test</th>
        <td><span class="lrg">10</span>1</td>
        <td><span class="lrg">7</span>1</td>
        <td><span class="lrg">3</span>1</td>
        <td><span class="lrg">1</span>1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What is the correct approach?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Colspan all columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398734/colspan-all-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<table id="my-table">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="4">Test</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="lrg">10</span>1</td>
        <td><span class="lrg">7</span>1</td>
        <td><span class="lrg">3</span>1</td>
        <td><span class="lrg">1</span>1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So what's `thead` for?

Comment: The <thead> tag is used to group header content in an HTML table.

Comment: @KingKing - "The thead element represents the block of rows that consist of the column labels (headings) for its parent table element."

Comment: As above, is there a way to do it without using col-span, since I am trying to avoid saying how many columns there will be since they will be dynamic.

Comment: @j08691 `thead` should exactly be what the OP wants. The `<th>Test</th` is what the OP **tried**.

Comment: @Jimmy looks like using `caption` is what you need, here is another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mVX93/14/) which adds the border to mimic 1 top row spanning all the columns.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell,

you can use this approach

```
<table id="my-table">
    <tr>
       <th colspan="4">Test</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="lrg">10</span>1</td>
      <td><span class="lrg">7</span>1</td>
      <td><span class="lrg">3</span>1</td>
      <td><span class="lrg">1</span>1</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

col span will allow you to stretch across four columns

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using col-span, since I am trying to avoid saying how many columns there will be since they will be dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to use a "header" as in `thead` and `th`?

I see from your question and comments is that you want a "heading" at top of the table which is *as wide* as the table and irrespective of the columns.

Would a simple `caption` properly styled with CSS, not work?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mVX93/15/

Answer (score 1):

You really should use `caption` for this.

```
<table id="my-table">
    <caption>Heading</caption>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="lrg">10</span>1</td>
            <td><span class="lrg">7</span>1</td>
            <td><span class="lrg">3</span>1</td>
            <td><span class="lrg">1</span>1</td>
        </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```