# Dividing table rows

Tags: html, css

I've got a very basic question. But I can not get this working correctly.

This is my table structure.

```
<table style="width:100%;">
   <tr style="background-color:#000;">
      <td style="color:#fff;">
        Fruits
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
        Lychee
      </td>
      <td>
        Mango
      </td>
      <td>
        Papaya
      </td>
      <td>
        Banana
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

How can I get he output to be as

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [the colspan attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp). Colspan allows one `td` to span many columns.

```
<table style="width:100%;">
   <tr style="background-color:#000;">
      <td style="color:#fff;" colspan="4">
        Fruits
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
        Lychee
      </td>
      <td>
        Mango
      </td>
      <td>
        Papaya
      </td>
      <td>
        Banana
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: When you've finished creating the tds, go back and count them, and then set the colspan. Sadly, there isn't really a non-hacky way to achieve "colspan=all" (setting colspan to a ridiculously large number, or doing `colspan="100%"` will probably work, but they aren't standardized so expect some browsers to get confused). [More info in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398734/colspan-all-columns)

Comment: The previous comment was in response to a now-deleted comment from the question asker about dynamically setting the colspan if the number of tds in the next row is uncertain. I'll leave it up even in the absence of the OP's comment since it's still useful info.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<td style="color:#fff;" colspan="4">`

see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/3oo2jmko/1/

```
<table style="width:100%;">
   <tr style="background-color:#000;">
      <td style="color:#fff;" colspan="4">
        Fruits
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
        Lychee
      </td>
      <td>
        Mango
      </td>
      <td>
        Papaya
      </td>
      <td>
        Banana
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```