HTML tables arbitrarily breaking to new page in PDF report
I am using JSReport (template engine: handlebars.js, pdf recipe: chrome-pdf) to generate PDF reports from html/css and I have encountered some very strange behavior with tables breaking to a new page randomly in very rare instances. An example:
table page break
As you can see, there is plenty of room for this table to fit on the first page, but it breaks after the first row.
I am using the CSS properties page-break-inside: auto; on my table elements and page-break-inside: avoid; page-break-after: auto; on my tr elements to allow tables spanning multiple pages to break to a new page properly.
Oddly, even if I remove these properties or try other combinations of them, i.e. setting just this table's properties to page-break-inside: avoid; and its tr properties to page-break-inside: avoid; page-break-after: avoid;, or removing all of these properties entirely, this table will still break in the same way.
When running different reports with different data, this same issue may or may not occur randomly in any table in the report, with the tables breaking at arbitrary rows (sometimes in the middle of the table, sometimes after just a few rows, etc). Overall, though, the issue is pretty rare. I'd estimate it occurs once in every ~25 tables generated.
I know this is a tough one to diagnose but I'm posting here as a last resort after trying every possible combination of CSS properties relevant to page breaks in hopes that someone has seen this or has some idea how I can debug this issue further.
EDIT:
Adding HTML and CSS of the table shown. Happy to provide any other info that may help.
TABLE CODE:


table {
  table-layout: auto;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 11px;
  page-break-inside: auto;
}

tbody tr {
  border-top: var(--border-tr);
  border-bottom: var(--border-tr);
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-after: auto;
}
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Number of transactions</th>
      <th>Gross*</th>
      <th>Fee*</th>
      <th>Tax*</th>
      <th>Net Amount*</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Buy</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>51,756.55</td>
      <td>0.00</td>
      <td>0.00</td>
      <td>51,756.55</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dividend</td>
      <td>71</td>
      <td>18,361.75</td>
      <td>0.00</td>
      <td>0.00</td>
      <td>18,361.75</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fee</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>59.47</td>
      <td>0.00</td>
      <td>0.00</td>
      <td>59.47</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Interest</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>43.05</td>
      <td>0.00</td>
      <td>0.00</td>
      <td>43.05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Management fee</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1,981.24</td>
      <td>0.00</td>
      <td>0.00</td>
      <td>1,981.24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sell</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>48,726.23</td>
      <td>7.87</td>
      <td>0.00</td>
      <td>48,718.36</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tax Withholding</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>351.28</td>
      <td>0.00</td>
      <td>0.00</td>
      <td>351.28</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Withdrawal</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>26,368.75</td>
      <td>0.00</td>
      <td>0.00</td>
      <td>26,368.75</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="100%"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="totalFooter">
      <td>Total</td>
      <td>115</td>
      <td>147,648.32</td>
      <td>7.87</td>
      <td>0.00</td>
      <td>147,640.45</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




Let's start with the rarity of this phenomenon. You say it occurs once in every ~25 tables generated, but you don't say anything about reproducibility. So if you take the exact same table, does it break consistently where you don't want it, or only sometimes?

If it is consistent, and thus reproducible, then it would be very helpful if you provided an example of the HTML that causes this problem. It will be very difficult to debug something we cannot reproduce.

@KIKOSoftware Yes, I should have mentioned that this table will break in the exact same way consistently if the report is generated with the same data. If different data is used and a different table breaks similar to this one, it will also consistently break in the same way each time the report is generated with that data. Editing the original question to include the HTML and CSS of the table shown.

I don't see anything weird, but I believe colspan="100%" isn't valid. It might be read as colspan="100"? See: MDM or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398734/colspan-all-columns

I've updated the post to show the actual HTML generated by the report renderer, but I agree that nothing looks out of the ordinary, so this is quite difficult to diagnose. I appreciate your response though. I do see now that using colspan in this way is not technically correct even if it works for tables with fewer than 100 columns. I will revise that.

I've made a CodePen of your code and tried printing to PDF, but I don't get what you get. Lot's of styling is missing and you're probably using headless Chrome to create the PDF. Anyway, I'm nowhere near reproducing your problem, let alone find a reason for it.

I did see that page-break-inside and page-break-after have been replaced, but I doubt that will make any difference.

@KIKOSoftware yeah, I understand that this is very hard to reproduce. Lots of HTML and CSS is missing and I am using JSReport for rendering which is not readily accessible so I may be out of luck getting any help here. This is just a shot in the dark mostly. In any case, I appreciate your effort.

@JaredJensen as Kiko pointed out, you must use break-inside not page-break-inside and break-after not page-break-after. Also you can use @media print media queries to add styles specifically for printing; I don't know if it would make any difference in this context, just throwing around ideas as without a way to replicate is very hard to point a solution
